# How can i solve id giving problems

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have a problem. I'am giving ids with **var nextId = players_online.length;** but if as example: player one connect to the game he gets id:1, second player gets id:2, then if first player disconnect other connected player gets same id:2

P.S also I can't do **var nextId = nextId+1;** because i draw players by their id players_online[id]. As example: player connect to the game he gets higher and higher id player = {id}, but then other player disconnect there will be no such id players_online[10] because one disconnected there is no player 10 in array...

Any ideas?( Somehow i have to give them id if it's not used by other player also it's can't by higher then players_online.length)

Comment: Can't you use `socket.id`?

Comment: yes i can but how can i render player later with socket.id. example: players_online[socket.id] there is no array with socket id

Comment: `io.of('/').connected` is an object that references all connected clients (to the `/` namespace, which is the default)

Comment: "yes i can but how can i render player later with socket.id. example: players_online[socket.id] there is no array with socket id" - Just use object instead?

Comment: i render players from array object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS object with integer keys instead of an array.

And generate nextId as maximal key + 1.

```js
var connections = {
    "1": { /* connection details */ },
    "2": { /* connection details */ },
    "4": { /* connection details */ }
};

// get all keys
var keys = Object.keys(connections);
console.log(keys);

// check for key existence
console.log("2" in connections);
console.log("3" in connections);

// delete connection 4
delete connections["4"];
console.log(Object.keys(connections));

function getNextId(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
        return Number(key)
    });
    var maxKey = Math.max.apply(null, keys);
    return maxKey + 1;
}

// get next id
var nextId = getNextId(connections);
console.log(nextId);

// add new connection
connections[nextId] = { /* connection details */ };
console.log(Object.keys(connections));
```

Or you can use Guid as an id:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/guid

Then simply generate new guid for new connection.